# Equation returns same value with consecutive inputs

Tags: javascript, return, equation

My current project requires a curve equation but instead of returning different values for different inputs, it returns the same value for several consecutive inputs.

**Code** *(asterisks for emphasis, not present in the actual code)*

```
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**67**/8.436912)^1.09424));
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**68**/8.436912)^1.09424));
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**69**/8.436912)^1.09424));
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**70**/8.436912)^1.09424));
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**71**/8.436912)^1.09424));
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**72**/8.436912)^1.09424));
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**73**/8.436912)^1.09424));
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**74**/8.436912)^1.09424));
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**75**/8.436912)^1.09424));
console.log(-21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (**76**/8.436912)^1.09424));
```

**Output**

```
46.87471111111112
55.434050000000006
55.434050000000006
55.434050000000006
55.434050000000006
55.434050000000006
55.434050000000006
55.434050000000006
55.434050000000006
34.42476363636364
```

As you can see, between the input values of 68-75 the output doesn't change.
I've tried several IDEs to make sure it wasn't a local issue. Can someone clue me in on what's going on?

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ay4twrm5/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing by `^` you mean to do exponentiation, except that `^` in JavaScript is not used in that way (it is the [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR) operator), to do exponents in JavaScript you need use `**` (not for emphasis, in actual code):

```js
function f(x) {
  return -21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + (x/8.436912)**1.09424);
}

console.log(f(67));
console.log(f(68));
console.log(f(69));
console.log(f(70));
console.log(f(71));
console.log(f(72));
console.log(f(73));
console.log(f(74));
console.log(f(75));
console.log(f(76));
```

Or, you could use `Math.pow`:

```js
function f(x) {
  return -21.6 + (594.6724 - -21.6)/(1 + Math.pow(x/8.436912, 1.09424));
}

console.log(f(67));
console.log(f(68));
console.log(f(69));
console.log(f(70));
console.log(f(71));
console.log(f(72));
console.log(f(73));
console.log(f(74));
console.log(f(75));
console.log(f(76));
```

Comment: I assumed that everything was alright since it compiled without errors. I'm embarrassed, to say the least. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Kudos for the formatting advice. Far more readable!